# Choice of loss function

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, word2vec

Here is a word2vec implementation:

```
%reset -f

import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np
import torch.functional as F
import torch.nn.functional as F

corpus = [
    'this test',
    'this separate test'
]

def get_input_layer(word_idx):
    x = torch.zeros(vocabulary_size).float()
    x[word_idx] = 1.0
    return x

def tokenize_corpus(corpus):
    tokens = [x.split() for x in corpus]
    return tokens

tokenized_corpus = tokenize_corpus(corpus)

vocabulary = []
for sentence in tokenized_corpus:
    for token in sentence:
        if token not in vocabulary:
            vocabulary.append(token)

word2idx = {w: idx for (idx, w) in enumerate(vocabulary)}
idx2word = {idx: w for (idx, w) in enumerate(vocabulary)}

window_size = 2
idx_pairs = []
# for each sentence
for sentence in tokenized_corpus:
    indices = [word2idx[word] for word in sentence]
    # for each word, threated as center word
    for center_word_pos in range(len(indices)):
        # for each window position
        for w in range(-window_size, window_size + 1):
            context_word_pos = center_word_pos + w
            # make soure not jump out sentence
            if context_word_pos < 0 or context_word_pos >= len(indices) or center_word_pos == context_word_pos:
                continue
            context_word_idx = indices[context_word_pos]
            idx_pairs.append((indices[center_word_pos], context_word_idx))

idx_pairs = np.array(idx_pairs) # it will be useful to have this as numpy array

vocabulary_size = len(vocabulary)

embedding_dims = 4
W1 = Variable(torch.randn(embedding_dims, vocabulary_size).float(), requires_grad=True)
W2 = Variable(torch.randn(vocabulary_size, embedding_dims).float(), requires_grad=True)
num_epochs = 1
learning_rate = 0.001

for epo in range(num_epochs):
    loss_val = 0
    for data, target in idx_pairs:
        x = Variable(get_input_layer(data)).float()
        y_true = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.array([target])).long())

        z1 = torch.matmul(W1, x)
        z2 = torch.matmul(W2, z1)

        log_softmax = F.log_softmax(z2, dim=0)

        loss = F.nll_loss(log_softmax.view(1,-1), y_true)
        print(float(loss))

        loss_val += loss.data.item()
        loss.backward()
        W1.data -= learning_rate * W1.grad.data
        W2.data -= learning_rate * W2.grad.data

        W1.grad.data.zero_()
        W2.grad.data.zero_()

        print(W1.shape)
        print(W2.shape)

        print(f'Loss at epo {epo}: {loss_val/len(idx_pairs)}')
```

This prints:

```
0.33185482025146484
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 0.041481852531433105
3.302438735961914
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 0.45428669452667236
2.3144636154174805
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 0.7435946464538574
0.33418864011764526
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 0.7853682264685631
1.0644199848175049
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 0.9184207245707512
0.4970806837081909
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 0.980555810034275
3.2861199378967285
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 1.3913208022713661
6.170125961303711
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 2.16258654743433
```

Modifying the code to use mse_loss change y_true to float :

```
y_true = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.array([target])).float())
```

Use mse_loss :

```
loss = F.mse_loss(log_softmax.view(1,-1), y_true)
```

Incorporated updates:

```
for epo in range(num_epochs):
    loss_val = 0
    for data, target in idx_pairs:
        x = Variable(get_input_layer(data)).float()
        y_true = Variable(torch.from_numpy(np.array([target])).float())

        z1 = torch.matmul(W1, x)
        z2 = torch.matmul(W2, z1)

        log_softmax = F.log_softmax(z2, dim=0)

        loss = F.mse_loss(log_softmax.view(1,-1), y_true)
        print(float(loss))

        loss_val += loss.data.item()
        loss.backward()
        W1.data -= learning_rate * W1.grad.data
        W2.data -= learning_rate * W2.grad.data

        W1.grad.data.zero_()
        W2.grad.data.zero_()

        print(W1.shape)
        print(W2.shape)

        print(f'Loss at epo {epo}: {loss_val/len(idx_pairs)}')
```

Output is now:

```
41.75048828125
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 5.21881103515625
16.929386138916016
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 7.334984302520752
50.63690948486328
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 13.664597988128662
36.21110534667969
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 18.190986156463623
5.304859638214111
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 18.854093611240387
9.802173614501953
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 20.07936531305313
15.515325546264648
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 22.018781006336212
30.408292770385742
torch.Size([4, 3])
torch.Size([3, 4])
Loss at epo 0: 25.81981760263443

-c:12: UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1, 3])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
```

Why does mse loss not work as well as nll loss ? Is it related to the PyTorch warning:

```
Using a target size (torch.Size([1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([1, 3])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size.
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input and target must have the same size for the [`nn.MSELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.MSELoss), because it is calculated by squaring the difference of the *i-th* element of the input and the *i-th* element of the target, i.e. `mse_i = (input_i - target_i) ** 2`.

Furthermore, your targets are non-negative integers in the range *[0, vocabulary_size]*, but you use log-softmax, which has values in range *[-∞, 0]*. With MSE the idea is to get the prediction value to the same value as the target, but the only overlap of the two intervals is 0. That means that every class besides 0 is unreachable.

MSE is a regression loss function and is simply not appropriate in this situation, since you are dealing with categorical data.